# Convert Lat/Long to XY Pixels for Albers or Lambert Projection Map of US

Tags: c#, javascript, coordinate-transformation

I'm using an open source map of the USA Contiguous (lower 48) with County lines.  Using Javascript or C#, I need to convert Lat/Long Coords to XY Pixels, to plot points on what appears to be either an Albers or Lambert Equal Area projection.  These seem to be the predominant projections for maps of the US lower 48.  Unfortunately, other posts are for simple Mercator projections.  Anyone have sweet Math skills who can help?

Comment: Can you provide some details on your end goal? I can think of several ways to convert lat/long into other types of coordinates but there's probably a better method than getting X/Y.

Comment: Sure, primary goal is to display dots/bubbles on the US map from a lat/long.

Comment: The map is a background image, so will use CSS to display the dots/bubbles on the map.  Node is pushing me real time lat/long json data from where people are calling us from, and we want to display that on the map.  It will of course be a bit fancier, like it disappears when they hang up and such.

Comment: You can just use the formulae from Wikipedia, [Albers projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albers_projection) and [Lambert cylindrical equal-area projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_cylindrical_equal-area_projection). They give `x` and `y` from lattitude `ϕ` and longitude `λ`.

Comment: Thank you, I saw those formulas.  Anyone smarter at Math than me, who can translate the Albers formulas into Javascript or C# code?

Comment: This is an interesting challenge but I'm not sure how to proceed. I would suggest a few alternatives, though, such as Google Maps API and even a D3.js map projection. Both seem better suited for this than regular CSS positioning. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is the map Geotiff encoded?